# When is energy converted to mass? What are the required conditions to do so?

Tags: special-relativity

I want to know whether every kind of energy is converted to mass like kinetic and potential energy?
Is it only possible for particles like electrons and protons or even either for big objects like a car or bus.
Please consider the minutest / smallest change in mass even 0.000000000000000000000001 kg of gain in mass?
I mean "relativistic mass" in case when the object is moving and "rest mass" in case when the object is at rest.
Can Rest mass too can increase when the gravitational potential energy of an object increases

Comment: Mass is simply a property of physical objects: things aren't converted to mass. The idea of converting things "to mass" is a one hundred year old idea, that really looks a bit shabby nowadays. Mass as a concept just isn't that important outside Newtonian mechanics anymore and there are no rigorous concepts of mass that aren't simply another way of expressing total energy. Mass is useful as an ID tag for subatomic particles and atoms, but it has some thorny, awkward properties which make it not useful anymore otherwise: see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/340132/26076)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to answer this from the perspective of quantum field theory.

Basically, there are these things called quantum fields which permeate everywhere in the universe. Each field has its own respective particle. You can think of a field like a pond. A ripple in the pond is a particle. In other words, a particle is a disturbance in a field. For example, a disturbance in the electron field is called an electron.

To create a ripple, energy must be used. By 'giving' energy to a field, you get a particle. Some of these particles have mass. Energy isn't really 'converted' into mass.

This answer strays a bit away from your particular need/special relativity, but hopefully, gives a fundamental view of the question.

Here are a few videos on the topic:

- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X9otDixAtFw
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FBeALt3rxEA
- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zNVQfWC_evg

Comment: So if you are moving at the speed of about 1000m/s somehow will there be increase in your mass? And if yes why you experienced a gain in mass

Comment: So how does QFT tell me about the gain in mass of a body while moving

Comment: +Arpit Bhardwaj Not exactly. Special relativity tells us that motion is relative, and if we are going in a car, and we pass a tree, the observer inside can say that the tree is in motion. Which object's mass increases - the car or the tree? There is something in special relativity called 'relativistic mass', which is based on m = E/c^2, i.e, the energy of motion turns into mass. This is true, but this definition of mass was disliked by Einstein, and modern physicists dislike it as well. Check out this Wikipedia page:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity#Controversy

Comment: So what really happens in this case

Comment: @ArpitBhardwaj Depends on your definition of 'mass'.

Comment: My definition of mass is that the property of a matter which depends on the way it interact with the higgs field

Comment: @ArpitBhardwaj Technically, no.

Comment: The first comment on your question by @WetSavannaAnimalakaRodVance was really good. You should check it out.

Comment: Ok so can the rest of object with respect to a rest person vary? That is both object and person are at rest in respect to each other

Comment: And finally tell me clearly whether there is relative mass which is variant when an object move. My school teacher said that the change in mass of a moving body is true only for particles like proton and election and neutrino too. Is this true? If yes why?

Comment: @ArpitBhardwaj When it comes to interactions with the Higgs Field, as far as my knowledge goes, no. Relativistic mass is a dead idea - Einstein implied that too. It is an incorrect and outdated point of view. Mass does not increase with an increase in velocity.

Some textbooks do say that relativistic mass is real - I'm in 9th grade myself, so I've noticed that textbooks often have outdated information. School textbooks improve accuracy as you go on to later grades. Take gravity for example - you overwrite Newton's equations with Einstein's as you progress into later grades.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to answer without considering any physic, just logic.

Let's say there are 257 types of energy. Let's say one of the 257 types of energy can be converted to mass.

Now, if we want to convert any type of energy to mass, we can convert the energy to the one type of energy that we can convert to mass, and then we can convert that energy to mass.

Comment: I want to know which kind of energy can be converted

Comment: All vehicles behave the same way. Size of vehicle does not matter. It does not matter whether the vehicle is battery powered, or nuclear, or flywheel powered.

Comment: You mean any kind of energy can be converted to mass

Comment: Could even kinetic energy

Comment: Are you perhaps interested about possible mass changes that occur when a flywheel powered car gains kinetic energy when it accelerates using the kinetic energy of the flywheel to gain kinetic energy?  And yes, any kind of energy can be converted to mass.

Comment: Yes but not accelerating but at constant velocity

Comment: Is this conversion only limited to elementary particles, proton & neutron